# I sent BCH to a segwit btc address, how can i get it back?

Tags: bitcoin-cash, segregated-witness

I accidentally sent bitcoin cash  to a segwit bitcoin address, please can anyone help me on how i can get it back. i tried using this recovery service, https://bch.btc.com/docs/help/bch_segwit_recovery
but they never replied me or responded to my email, please what can i do?

Comment: Your best option is to contact other (well known) BCH mining pools. It's not practical to broadcast the tx on your own (and leaves you open to losing all your coins). Essentially, without a miner's support, you are out of luck

Comment: ok, what pool do you suggest, i have no clue.